# Can I create commited use instance before making status of my purchase to become Active

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have purchased committed use instance in GCP. But status is in a pending state. I want to create instance asap but waiting for the status to become active. So can I create instance first and then the respective instance come under committed discounts?

Comment: yes, the price will be discount after committed is active.

Answer (score 2):

That is right, you can create first the GCE instances then the discounts will automatically by applied to applicable instances in the region you specified.

Please note that the commitment, takes effect at midnight of the following day after your purchase.

Please take a look on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#purchasecommitment) for more references.